# Setting the FileUpload value using VB.net inside of a WebBrowser Control

Tags: vb.net, file-upload, webbrowser-control

I'm setting up a program that displays a website that has a FileUpload object.  I wanted to have my program set the default path for the FileUpload object but I can't seem to get it to work.  Here is my current attempt:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("uploaded_file").SetAttribute("Value", UploadDefault)
```

It doesn't seem to be working, however.  Does anybody how I can get my desired result?  I'm using VB.net so all .net answers are acceptable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For HTMLElement of input type="file" [value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh466236.aspx) attribute is **read-only**, because of security reasons.

> input type=file   The value, a file name, typed by the user into the
>   control. Unlike other controls, this value is read-only.

Comment: Well that explains why my method didn't work.  Do you perhaps have a solution to my problem?

Comment: FileUpload has only limited number of methods that are supported by browsers; http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html#value

Answer (score 0):

you can use gecko with xullrunner

Dim oFile As New GeckoInputElement(GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByName("file1")(0).DomObject)

oFile.Value = fileNametoUpload